# Geoserver 2.11 Beta : SpatiaLite as data source proper installation

Tags: geoserver, installation, spatialite

I am configuring Spatialite as data source in Geoserver 2.11 Beta (Windows 10 Pro) but I am only having SpatiaLite (JNDI) extension properly installed, the other SpatiaLite Data Source does not appear in my Vector Data Sources at all. I followed this [manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/spatialite/index.html).

Do I am  missing something here?

Comment: please check in the log file to see if there are any relevant messages and then add them to your question

Comment: I have the same issue with Geoserver 2.10 on Ubuntu 16 (with Tomcat 8). I look at Geosever log, but there's nothing about SpatiaLite.

What checks can I do to find out the problem?